# C: Dynamically allocate a table

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I'm developing a small code that reads numbers from a file and stores them in an table. The file tells the user in the beginning the number of rows of the table (number of columns is fixed: 3)
E.g. of file:
**3

1  2 20.5

1  4  9.22

2  6  11.7

1  3  12.1**

As the title says, I need to allocate the table according to the number of rows that appear on my file. Can anyone give me a hand?
So far I did this:
Allocation

```
int** table = malloc(r * sizeof(int)); //r = num of rows
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3); //3 is the number of columns
```

Filling

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %lf", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    ->  table[i][0]=a;
    ->  table[i][1]=b;
    ->  table[i][2]=c;
    }
}
```

But in the lines I pointed out with "->" I'm getting an error saying: expression must have pointer-to-object type.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Do you have any code that does not work?

Comment: Glow the array via `realloc()`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry I didnt make it clear. The problem is that i dont know how to do it

Comment: @MikeCAT what do you mean with "glow the array"?

Comment: Increase allocated size as you need.

Comment: Why `realloc`? The size is known from the file. `malloc` will suffice.

Comment: we are not a code writing service.please clarify your actual problem you are facing

Comment: @Raildex Sorry I've corrected the post

Comment: If you are using C99 and don't need to return that table from the function, then make it a Variable Length Array. int table[r][3];

Comment: Btw, I am not getting that error when compiling with GCC. Are you sure the mistake isn't somewhere else?

Comment: does it need to be a two dimensional array? a one dimensional array is easier to handle

Comment: Why does your file show `3` followed by `4` rows of data? You don't even need to know how many rows to begin with. If you know there are always 3-columns, that simplifies things further. Simply declare a *pointer-to-array* of `int [3]` (or `float [3]`, whatever type) and allocate some number of rows. Read lines and convert to `int` and fill rows until you run out of your allocated rows and `realloc` additional rows and keep going. Repeat until you run out of lines to read, or memory, whichever occurs first.

Answer (score 3):

**Choosing the Correct Type**

First, if you are needing to read numbers from the file, e.g.:

```
1 2 20.5
```

Then reading into an `int` value won't capture the last *floating-point* column. You will need to either create a struct between two `int` and one `float`, or simply use `float` (or `double`) as the type.

**Choosing The Correct Aggregate Object Type**

While you could use a *pointer-to-pointer* (e.g. `float **`) and allocate some number of pointers, and then allocate a block of memory for 3-`float` for each row and then assign to each allocated pointer -- if the number of columns are fixed at three, then using a *pointer-to-array* allows a single-allocation/single-free that is much easier than allocating a pointer *and* a block to hold 3-`float` for every row.

Instead of using `float **table;` you would use `float (*table)[3]` (a *pointer-to-array* of `float[3]`)

**Allocation/Reallocation Using Pointer-to-Array**

Whenever you need to read and store an unknown number of any object type, you will generally allocate some number to begin with, keep a counter of the number available and then number used, and then when `used == available`, `realloc()` adding more storage for your collection of objects and keep going. With any memory allocation, you must ***validate*** the allocation succeeds by ***checking the return** before you use that block of memory in your code.

Choose the way you will add memory each time you `realloc()`. You can either add storage for some new fixed number of objects each time (e.g. like adding `10 * sizeof object` to `available` each time you `realloc` (fine for a small unknown number), but allocations/reallocations are relatively expensive operations.

To balance reasonable growth of memory size against the number of times you have to reallocate, a general scheme is to double the number `available` each time you reallocate (e.g. you can initially allocate `2` objects, and then each reallocation would result in `4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, etc...` Which with `20` reallocation would result in storage for over `2,000,000` objects, while if adding `10-more` each time you would have storage for `200`.

**How You Read Data From Your File**

If you use *formatted-input* functions like `fscanf()` to read from your file, it is a fragile scheme. One extraneous character in the file can break your read from that point forward.

A better approach is to use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` which will read a line of data from your file at a time into a sufficiently sized character array, which you can then parse the needed values from. That way you can independently validate your read of a line, and the extraction of needed values from that line -- and -- if you have extra characters in the line, the worst that can happen is you fail to get the values from that 1-line, but the read and extraction from all others in unaffected.

You have multiple ways to extract values from a line of data read into a character array, `sscanf()`, `strtol / strtof, etc..`, `strtok / strsep`, or any of the other string-functions, or simply use a pair of pointers to bracket the characters you need.

To open your file with the filename given as the 1st argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is given), you can do:

```
#define COLS   3       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 256
...
    char line[MAXC];        /* buffer to hold each line read */
    ...
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {        /* read / validate each line */
       ...
        /* parse / validate 3 floats from line into arr */
        if (sscanf (line, "%f %f %f", &arr[used][0], &arr[used][1], &arr[used][2]) != 3)
            continue;
        
        used++;                             /* increment no. of used rows */
    }
```

Above, you will read each line into `line`, and then attempt to parse 3-`float` values from that line with `sscanf()`. If it fails, you simply `continue` and read the next line. If it succeeds, you have extracted the values into your array (table) and you simply need to increment the number of rows `used` and go read the next line.

The allocation of storage for an unknown number of lines of data starts when you allocate an initial number of values, e.g.

```
    float (*arr)[COLS];     /* pointer-to-array float[3] */
    size_t  used  = 0,      /* allocated rows used */
            avail = 2;      /* allocated rows available */
    ...
    /* allocate initial 'avail' rows / validate EVERY allocaiton */
    if ((arr = malloc (avail * sizeof *arr)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-avail");
        return 1;
    }
```

Then within your loop, before adding a row you your array, you make sure there is storage available by check if reallocation is needed by checking `if (used == avail)`. And if a reallocation is required, you reallocate to a *temporary pointer*, so when (not if) `realloc()` fails returning `NULL`, you don't overwrite the pointer to your data with `NULL` losing your pointer to the beginning of that block of memory -- meaning it can no longer be freed -- creating a *memory-leak*.

Only after you ***validate*** that the reallocation succeeded do you assign the reallocated block of memory to your pointer, e.g.

```
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {        /* read / validate each line */
        if (used == avail) {                /* is arr full, needs reallocation? */
            /* always realloc to a temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (arr, 2 * avail * sizeof *arr);
            if (!tmp) {                     /* validate EVERY reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-arr");
                break;                      /* break, don't exit, arr still good */
            }
            arr = tmp;                      /* assign reallocated block to arr */
            avail *= 2;                     /* update no. of available rows */
        }
        ...
```

Above just uses the reallocation scheme of doubling the size of the block of memory each time `realloc()` is called. If the reallocation succeeds, then update the number available by multiplying it by two.

If `realloc()` fails, since you used a *temporary pointer* in your call to `realloc()` your original pointer still points to the data you had before the call to `realloc()`. So there is no need to exit the program, the data you have collected at that point is still good (you are just out of memory). So simply `break;` your read-loop and process the data you have.

**Putting It Altogether**

If you put it altogether, you would have something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS   3       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 256

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char line[MAXC];        /* buffer to hold each line read */
    float (*arr)[COLS];     /* pointer-to-array float[3] */
    size_t  used  = 0,      /* allocated rows used */
            avail = 2;      /* allocated rows available */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* allocate initial 'avail' rows / validate EVERY allocaiton */
    if ((arr = malloc (avail * sizeof *arr)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-avail");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!fgets (line, MAXC, fp))            /* read / validate / discard 1st line */
        return 1;
    
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {        /* read / validate each line */
        if (used == avail) {                /* is arr full, needs reallocation? */
            /* always realloc to a temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (arr, 2 * avail * sizeof *arr);
            if (!tmp) {                     /* validate EVERY reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-arr");
                break;                      /* break, don't exit, arr still good */
            }
            arr = tmp;                      /* assign reallocated block to arr */
            avail *= 2;                     /* update no. of available rows */
        }
        /* parse / validate 3 floats from line into arr */
        if (sscanf (line, "%f %f %f", &arr[used][0], &arr[used][1], &arr[used][2]) != 3)
            continue;
        
        used++;                             /* increment no. of used rows */
    }
    if (fp != stdin)                        /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < used; i++)       /* output used rows */
        printf (" %4g  %4g  %6.2f\n", arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2]);
    
    free (arr);                             /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

(**note:** above the first line is just read and discarded. Since you are dynamically allocating memory, you can simply read each data line and add it to your, reallocate when needed, and repeat until you run out of lines to read or run out of memory, whichever occurs first)

**question:** Why can you delete the read and discard of the first-line and the program still operates the same? For example, why can you delete the two lines `if (!fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) return 1;` without any effect on program operation?

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `dat/rowsfloats.txt` and the program compiled to `bin/readrowsfloat`, you would receive:

```
$ ./bin/readrowsfloat dat/rowsfloats.txt
    1     2   20.50
    1     4    9.22
    2     6   11.70
    1     3   12.10
```

All lines have been successfully read and all values stored in your array.

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/readrowsfloat dat/rowsfloats.txt
==25760== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25760== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25760== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25760== Command: ./bin/readrowsfloat dat/rowsfloats.txt
==25760==
    1     2   20.50
    1     4    9.22
    2     6   11.70
    1     3   12.10
==25760==
==25760== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25760==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25760==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 5,744 bytes allocated
==25760==
==25760== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25760==
==25760== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25760== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

**Take It Slow**

There is a lot of information included here, and it ended up longer than I anticipated, so slow down and take your time to understand what is happening in each line and why. Dynamic memory allocation isn't difficult, but it has to be taken step-by-step.

In summary, all you are doing all allocating a block of memory where you can store things. If you need a bigger block of memory, you just reallocate. When you reallocate, you use a temporary pointer to avoid creating a memory-leak if `realloc()` fails. When you are done, you simply `free()` the memory you have allocated. The rest is just arithmetic keeping track of how much you allocated and how much is available.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

With variable length array, you can write:

```
int table[r][3];
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        table[i][j] = value_from_fscanf;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use VLA, since the second dimension is fixed, you can write:

```
int (*table)[3] = malloc(r * 3 * sizeof(int));
```